# windows 8.1 RTM fingerprint option missing

Tags: hp-elitebook, fingerprint, windows-8.1

I am running Windows 8.1 on Elitebook 8460p. I was looking forward to configuring fingerprint logon. However the fingerprint option is missing.

I verified in Device manager; the driver is installed. Is there a way to enable this sign-in option ?

Comment: is you windows 8.1 volume licensed?

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 No. MSDN license